# Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu wont wake up from suspension

Tags: suspend, power-management, 21.10

I've been having this problem for a very long time  where my Lenovo Ideapad 5 14" goes to sleep for me either closing the lid or just leaving it. When I try to wake it up my touching the keyboard or clicking/moving the mouse . I even went out to reinstalling my operating system with no difference. Don't know what to do anymore.

Thanks in advance to everyone that helps.

Neofetch Specs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO8zA.png

Link to lenovo firmware (Only for Windows): https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht003029-lenovo-system-update-update-drivers-bios-and-applications

Comment: The power button might be used to resume after suspend.  Have you check for any firmware updates from your vendor?  Those might help on all sorts of odd problems.

Comment: Only holding the power button for a couple of second (this turns it off). Would you mean to update the BIOS, I haven't found any that I could run on ubuntu.

Comment: Just a touch on the button, not holding it, resumes my laptop.  BIOS is probably not the right name any more with UEFI machines, so "firmware".  Up to the vendor how they supply the updates, windows executable, DOS executable, or just a file which the machine can use to update itself.

Comment: I use the command sudo fwupdmgr update and it says that there are no updatable devices, and it lists my devices. Also, it should simply wake up when I move the mouse or tap the keyboard I'd think.

Comment: Two notable misconceptions: (1) *it should simply wake up when I move the mouse or tap the keyboard* No, it shouldn't. Suspension is a state where everything but the RAM is turned off (RAM keeps the current session "alive"). In laptops suspension and waking up is typically triggered by the lid switch but also the power button, some as in desktops, if suspended with the lid open. (...)

Comment: (...) (2) Firmware (BIOS/UEFI and others) updates *should* be OS independent/agnostic. Ideally it should be possible without any OS involvement. That some vendors only publish Windows/DOS exes for that purpose is unfortunate but more often than not there are alternative ways. More often than not all it takes is to read the additional notes, the "fine print" and/or do a google search. `fwupmgr` is a generic tool for Linux distros to be in equal footing but it depends entirely on manufacturers enrolling their updates.

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question and add brand/model and hardware specifications and/or even a direct link for the firmware update page for your model. We'll see what can be done about it.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/ht500008 -> ***Note: The BIOS download text file (readme) contains information about flashing the BIOS from a USB key where applicable. Check the Drivers & Software page to see if there is an ISO image that can be used with Linux for your system. Visit our support home page, select the product > click Drivers & software.***

Answer (score 0):

the issue lies with PCI express power management. Your problems will go away if you switch it off. It it possible on Windows but I haven't found out how to do it in Ubuntu.

I will have to go back to Windows if I can't do the same under Ubuntu.

Martin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have such kind of problem for a very long with my lenovo ideapad. I have tried different methods but none worked out for me. So i decided to go back to my windows and updated my Bios then it worked out for me. Now, i can suspend and wake it up without any problem. I suggest you should updating your Bios also

Comment: Thank you for answering, since then I have moved to Arch Linux and the problem still continued. What seemed to fix the problem most of (but not all) the time was switching to kernel 6.2.10-zen1-1-zen.